# Compare PDF files visually(drawings and highlights) and merge the differences

Tags: pdf, merge

I am trying to compare and merge 2 pdf files which has text, drawings and highlights/comments.

The old file will have highlights and comments but new file will have changes to text and drawing with out highlights or comments, I need to be able compare all  the differences and merge the highlights and comments from old file back to the new file where applicable.

So far I have found some tools that does the comparison but not the merge/highlights. I have tested DiffPDF and it works for comparing but I am not sure how I can use that to merge the files. Any software/tool that does this already and is there a way to do the merge with diffpdf ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do what you are asking. Even if you go low level, there are big challenges to face. PDF is very different from other document formats in that there is no semantic structure embedded in the document, so it would be very hard for something like a merge process to be able to figure out what to do. You may need to try a completely different approach. Remember that PDF was designed essentially to display identically on different platforms. It was never designed for document editing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I understand that it is not an easy task, but I was hoping there is a way to merge at least the Highlights of the documents like copy Highlights from PDF A and move it to PDF B and then user can manually validate the changes. And you said about a different approach, any ideas on that ?

Comment: If you are willing to go low-level, the annotations are in a dictionary that is distinct from the so-called content stream, so you could copy the target PDF and append the annotation dictionary from the source. However, the annotations are specified purely geometrically, so this will only work if there are not text changes. Depending on your platform, there are APIs to get the contents of PDF document dictionaries. It is not trivial, but an experienced programmer should be able to copy annotations without much difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Check this library for PDF Compare and highlighting the differences.

https://github.com/vinsguru/pdf-util